# QGIS 2.2 rendering problems

Tags: qgis, geometry, error

i have a problem with some geometry. 
When i run the check geometry validity i get an error coming back that the rings are not closed, so recangular forms that i have surveyed are showing up as triangles. When I put the layer in editing mode, the rectangles show their rectangular forms but go back to triangles when i turn off the editing, not sure if this is caused by the codelist on my total station.
a solution i found was to use polygons to lines and then lines to polygons and replace my original polygons with these new ones. 
This can be quite time consuming so was wondering if anyone has a quicker fix for this or if there is a way of preventing this.
The problem only occurs with polygons (i use a codelist created on a Leica TC1200)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This clearly is a new issue for QGIS 2.2 (I tried this on Windows 7 and MacOSX 10.9). The same layer of rectangular polygons is displayed correctly in QGIS before version 2.2, but as triangles in version 2.2. I guess we'll need to file a bug report. (just created: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9686) only affecting version 2.2.0. It has been fixed and the fix will be included in the next major or minor release (and master/testing builds).

As a temporary workaround you can disable rendering simplification on affected layers' properties individually.

[image]

If you often have such layers you may also disable this optimization completely in Settings->Options->Rendering->Enable feature simplification by default for newly added layers

Comment: I found the simplify geometry worked to correct the errors.
I also discovered that the problem was importing 3D data. I usually produce 2D and 3D shapefiles as it can be useful to see 3D shapes in AutoCAD. So importing 2D data would probably avoid the problem